# What can I do when usermod alert me that user does not exist

Tags: linux, centos

I accidentally deleted the home directory of a user, and I'm trying to recreate it using `usermod`. That command is telling me that the user doesn't exist, even though `id` correctly returns information about the user.

I'm using CentOS 6.4.

Comment: Delete the user and recreate it ?

Comment: Please post your `usermod` command.

Comment: Either recreate the user or try create a test user and rename the home folder as your user. Its not a big deal :)